# Ubuntu 14.04: very slow response from a 64 bit fresh install on 4 core server

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, radeon, performance

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop version (64 bit) on the

- Dell quad-core (2.3 Ghz) AMD64 server with 8 GB of memory.

The graphics card is

- NVIDIA CK8-04 Pro (System details says "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits")).

With just the Ubuntu installed, the GUI response was laggy but not slow enough to stop me from working. The response when using the terminal was good. But, after I installed the Oracle 12c database, even though the database has not been started, the performance of the machine has deteriorated a lot. I have click on the title bar of a window and wait for some time before the focus can be switched to that window. Even in the terminal, I type the commands and wait for some time for the typed letters to appear. I cannot use the system like this.

The `lshw` command gives the following:

```
configuration: driver=radeon latency=66 mingnt=8
```

From the image below you can see high CPU usage with only the OS and screen shot app running. The memory usage is less than 1/4th.

[image]

The following link shows the processes running:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Correct me if I am wrong; but isnt the Radeon Driver for AMD/ATI machines?

Comment: Did you try installing graphic drivers? The Software Sources program will have a tab called "Additional Drivers"..